# XCode 7.1.1 - Launch Images for iPhone 6, 6s and 6 plus

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uilaunchimagefile

I was recently adding the Launch Images for my app to support iPhone 6, 6s and 6 plus resolutions.
I read somewhere that apple dropped support for the `LaunchImages` form `images.xcassets`. And so I decided to add the `LaunchScreen`. Adding the `LaunchScreen` resolves the zoomed view issue but it messes up all my views. Is this just because of the my laziness in not using Autolayout constraints or is there anything else I can do? I went through all the places where I have `setFrame` and I have always set the width with respect to `self.view.frame.size.width`

Any help will be great as to how I can resolve this issue. I have also gone through my `.xibs` and clicked on the AutoLayout and Size Classes checkboxes, still no luck.

Even pointing me the right direction will be great! I have gone through multiple SO questions and implemented the people's suggestions like adding the UILaunchImagesName in the Info.plist, etc.

I hope I've been clear in asking the question.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Apple did not drop support form `LaunchImages` using `images.xcassets`. They are saying that the new `LaunchScreen` is the way to go, and autolayout is really suggest with all the device screen sizes. You might want to add some more example code en a reproducible example, now we can't really do more then guess.

Comment: @rckoenes sorry for the late reply! I have added the LaunchScreen but self.view.frame.size.width and self.view.frame.size.height returns 320 and 568 for iphone 6, 6s, 6plus. So i'm not sure why this is happening